# Using Ruby sub method with array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Ruby's sub method to clean some strings this way:

```
test_string = 'we serve food and drinks'
=> "we serve foo and drinks"
test_string.sub('and drinks', '')
=> "we serve foo"
```

How can I use the same method over an array of strings like this one:

```
test_array = ['we serve foo and drinks', 'we serve toasts and drinks', 'we serve alcohol and drinks']
```

I tried the following to get rid of **"and drinks"** part of each string in this array but I couldn't remove them.

```
test_array.each do |testArray|
  test_array.sub('and drinks', '')
end
=> ["we serve foo and drinks", "we serve toasts and drinks", "we serve kale and drinks"]
```

Comment: Please, define "doesn't work". What result did you expect? Why did you expect that result? What result did you get? Why is the result you got not the result you expect? How did you get that result? Please, provide a [mcve], along with all error messages and warnings you get, the expected and actual results, the expected and actual behaviors, and a clear problem statement including examples, and specifications of all corner cases, special cases, edge cases, and all rules for how to get the expectecd results. At the moment, you simply ignore the result of `sub`, so how do you even know that …

Comment: "it doesn't work"?

Comment: I think what didn't work is clear when you compare the two examples I've provided. I was able to achieve a very clear result using sub method when applied on one string however it didn't yield the same result when same scenario was applied to an array of strings, which are basically duplicates of my first example. The initial answer landed in 7 minutes with a working solution so I assume that was clear enough.

Comment: "it didn't yield the same result when same scenario was applied to an array of strings" – except it *isn't* the same scenario. In the first scenario, you save the output of `sub`. In the second, you throw it away. It is not clear what you expect to happen there.

Comment: Fair enough, I've edited the question to clarify the problem for future viewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `#map`

```
test_array.map do |testArray|
  testArray.sub('and drinks', '')
end
```

You could also mutate each string *(which isn't recommended)*

```
test_array.each do |testArray|
  testArray.sub!('and drinks', '')
end
```

Comment: shouldn't be `testArray` within the block?

Answer (score 3):

```
test_array.map {|element| element.sub('and drinks', '') }
```

`#map` method is returning array of changed elements